# How can I delete printed line in python?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I would love to print a counting down and in each second delete a line:

```
import time
for x in range(3):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
    #Delete previous line
```

How can I do?
**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends what terminal are you using. You can simulate the deletion of the line with carriage-return characters `\r` and spaces `' '`, for example:

```
import time

for x in range(3):
    print(x, end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\r    \r', end='', flush=True)
```

For more advanced solution, look at the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) module.

Comment: Thanks it works, but what means the `flush` keyword?

Comment: @OrangoMango `flush` means that data that are printed aren't buffered but printed on the screen immediately.

Comment: Would `print('\r    \r', end='', flush=True)` work if previously only `print(x)` is done?

Comment: `\r` simply moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line; it's terminal dependent whether writing over previous text replaces it or is rendered in an "overstrike" fashion (e.g., `-\r|` could be rendered as `|` or a plus-like symbol, depending on the output device.) (*Most* terminals will replace. The obvious exception would be a teletype-like device that can't easily replace something already printed on paper.)